# Saving State of Objects in GXT

Tags: java, gwt, state, gxt

Is there a way to store the state of objects in GXT?

That is, having a dynamically configurable GUI built in GXT, you can add your own widgets 'on-the-fly' in any order you like - with your own custom *everything*. Is there a way to save the state of all the objects, so one can load the profile back at a later date?

EDIT:

Or is there any kind of state-saving in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried it but following dicussion might help you:

http://www.extjs.com/forum/showthread.php?p=445368